# Ionic 3 - network-information plugin - Object(...) is not a function(…)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I need to implement network information plugin in an ionic 3 angular 4 project. I have installed a network plugin using

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information  
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/network@5.0.0
```

After installation, I have used this plugin in ***app.component.ts*** but I'm getting an error as

> **ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function(…)** on either device or emulator.

I'm sharing native-core and plugin versions that I have used in this app.

```
"@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0"
"@ionic-native/network": "5.0.0"
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1"
```

**Please Note:** 
I have tried upgrading `"@ionic-native/core" to "5.2.0"` and `"@ionic-native/network" to "5.2.0"`. But the issue was not resolved.

Here, I cannot degrade plugin npm version or `"@ionic-native/core" to "4.2.0"` as I have many plugins used in this app which are working fine @ version "5.0.0".

Below is my ***app.component.ts***

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
...
constructor(private network: Network) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        // watch network for a disconnection
        let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
            console.log('network disconnected!');
        });
    })
}
```

Below is my ***package.json***

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    ...
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.0.0",
    ...
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
  }
```

Below is my ***development system*** information

```
Ionic:
    ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins

System:
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/###/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? Please help me as I'm not able to move forward without the network plugin. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `/ngx` import which is for Ionic version 4. If you go read the [changelog](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/v5/CHANGELOG.md) you will see that version 5 and up `Requires Angular 7.1 and TypeScript 3.1`.

Try to downgrade plugin to 4.20.0 like this :

`npm uninstall @ionic-native/network`

then
`npm install @ionic-native/network@4.20.0`

And remove ngx in import like this :
`import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';`

Answer (score 1):

Since the release of Ionic 4, Installing Ionic Native for Ionic 3 requires you to add `@4` to get the latest compatible version. 
In this case, and all others involving Ionic 3, you should do it like this

```
npm install @ionic-native/network@4
```

for network,

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner@4
```

for Barcode Scanner,

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/network@4, 
npm install --save @ionic-native/bluetooth-le@4
```

for BluetoothLE.